# spring.mvc.view.suffix does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm new with spring boot, and I've wrote the WelcomeController which is below.

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "homePage";
    }
}
```

Then I add `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html` to the application.properties. 
I suppose only the `localhost:8080/home.html` url would render homePage.html. But when I visit `localhost:8080/home`, I still get the homePage.html, not a 404 error as I supposed.

How can I make url which only end with '.html' legal? Why the `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html` config don't work?

Comment: It doesn't do what you think it does. What it does it will append `.html` to the name of the view returned from the controller. It has no influence on the incoming URLs it is only for interpreting the name of the view nothing else.

Comment: What result are you getting from this url: localhost:8080/home.html   ?

Comment: can you post your other config

Comment: I think the user wants to enforce validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting confused with the purpose of the property. Basically all it's doing is stating what's the extension the view file will have in the server. 
Read a bit about it here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html around chater 74.8

I believe that you are just trying to validate the url endpoint and make sure it ends in ".html"

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        if (!isValidEndpoint(uri)) {
            throw new InvalidUrlException();
        }

        return "homePage";
    }

    private boolean isValidEndpoint(String url) {
        return url.endsWith(".html");
    }
}

@ResponseStatus(code=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="The url needs to end with '.html'")
class InvalidUrlException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public InvalidUrlException() {
        super();
    }
}
```